# Parsing xml from .xml responce.+iphone

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

i want to prase the xml like below:-

```
    <RoomType productId="1215560;1973855;189629" name="Standard" nights="2" startDate="2011-08-10T00:00:00-04:00" isAvailable="true" roomId="3" hotelRoomTypeId="1973855">
    <Avail offset="0" status="true" />
        <Avail offset="1" status="true" />
            <Occup occupId="1215560;1973855;189629;2;2;2" maxAdult="4" maxChild="2" price="416.46" tax="60.66" dblBed="true" avrNightPrice="208.23">
            <Board bbId="1" name="Continental Breakfast" price="0" default="false" />
                <Room seqNum="1" adultNum="2" childNum="2">
                    <Child age="8" />
                        <Child age="10" />
                    </Room>
                    <Price offset="0" value="208.23" />
                    <Price offset="1" value="208.23" />
            </Occup>
</RoomType>
```

How do i parse such xml file in iphone.

Is there any method to parse such.

Please help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSXMLParser. In the delegate method you can get the values from the dictionary as follows:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
if(elementName isEqualToString:@"RoomType")
{
NSString *productId = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"productId"];
}
}
```

Similarly you can do for the other items.

Comment: Were you able to follow this method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSXMLParser for parsing xmls. You have to implement NSXMLParserDelegate methods. You can check the ParseOperation class in [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394) code sample for a very basic implementation of xml parser delegate.